# Different results before and after OneHotEncoder

Tags: python, numpy

I encoded y vector using OneHotEncoder, run my neural network and got output.
Here `a` represents my y vector, and `b` stands for prediction result

```
a = np.array([[0., 0., 1., 0.],
       [0., 0., 1., 0.],
       [0., 0., 1., 0.],
       [0., 0., 1., 0.],
       [0., 0., 1., 0.],
       [0., 0., 1., 0.],
       [1., 0., 0., 0.],
       [1., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 1., 0.],
       [0., 0., 1., 0.]])
b=np.array([[0., 0., 0., 1.],
       [1., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 1., 0.],
       [0., 1., 0., 0.],
       [1., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 1., 0.],
       [0., 0., 1., 0.],
       [1., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 1.],
       [0., 1., 0., 0.]])
print(np.mean(a!=b))
print(np.mean(np.argmax(a,1)!=np.argmax(b,1)))
```

but after reverting encoding (using `np.argmax(a,1)`) and I get output:

```
0.35
0.7
```

Shouldn't these values be equal?

Comment: One hot encoding is used when you are dealing with categorical variables. Why did you encode integers in the first place?

Comment: For achitecture purposes, I need to transform for example 1 to [0,1,0,0], 3 to  [0,0,0,1] and so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue comes from the fact that `a!=b` returns an array of arrays, checking whether the elements at each index are different. The first returns an array of arrays where the first value is `[False False  True  True]`, meaning that for the first items in `a` and `b`, the first two entries are the same, and the last two are different. Try the following:

```
print(a!=b)
>>>[[False False  True  True], [ True False  True False] ...
```

The second returns a single array comparing the indices as you wanted:

```
print(np.argmax(a,1)!=np.argmax(b,1))
>>>[ True  True False  True  True False  True False  True  True]
```